# Why doesn't IServerStreamWriter send notification responses?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, grpc

I work on a cross-platform application. For connection between them, I use gRPC technology. When a client connects to server, it is added to an observers list located in server implementation. When a client connects, I want to send a message to the rest of connected clients telling them that a new client connected. The problem is that when I want to send a response to clients that a new client connected, using the observers from my list, I get the following exception:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: 'Status(StatusCode=Unknown, Detail="Exception was thrown by handler.")'
```

This is my proto file where I declared my server:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package com.example.grpc.chat;

message ChatMessage {
    string from = 1;
    string message = 2;
}

message ChatMessageFromServer {
    ChatMessage message = 2;
}

service ChatService {
    rpc Login(ChatMessage ) returns (stream ChatMessageFromServer);
}
```

The server code :

```
 public class ChatServiceImpl : ChatService.ChatServiceBase
    {
        private static HashSet<IServerStreamWriter<ChatMessageFromServer>> responseStreams = new HashSet<IServerStreamWriter<ChatMessageFromServer>>();

        /*
         * if the stream object (from "for" statement inside this method) isn't the responseStream object given in the list with parameters,
         * the rest of clients aren't notified when a new login request is pushed.
         */
        public override async Task Login(global::Com.Example.Grpc.Chat.ChatMessage request,
            IServerStreamWriter<global::Com.Example.Grpc.Chat.ChatMessageFromServer> responseStream, 
            ServerCallContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Login method from server");
            responseStreams.Add(responseStream);

            // Create a server message that wraps the client message
            var message = new ChatMessageFromServer
            {
                Message = new ChatMessage
                {
                    From = "login",
                    Message = "hello"
                }
            };
            // If stream variable isn't equal to responseStream from list of parameters, the client corresponding to that stream isn't notified and it's thrown the above exception
            foreach (var stream in responseStreams)
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(message);
            }
        }

    }
```

The client code where the client send a login request:

```
public partial class ChatForm : Form
    {
        private const string Host = "localhost";
        private const int Port = 9090;

        private ChatService.ChatServiceClient _chatService;

        public ChatForm()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            InitializeGrpc();
        }

        private void InitializeGrpc()
        {
            // Create a channel
            var channel = new Channel(Host + ":" + Port, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);

            // Create a client with the channel
            _chatService = new ChatService.ChatServiceClient(channel);
        }

        private async void ChatForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var message = new ChatMessage
            {
                From = "Unknown",
                Message = "Login text"
            };

            // Open a connection to the server
            try
            {
                using (var call = _chatService.Login(message))
                {
                    // Read messages from the response stream
                    while (await call.ResponseStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None))
                    {
                        var serverMessage = call.ResponseStream.Current;
                        var otherClientMessage = serverMessage.Message;
                        var displayMessage = string.Format("{0}:{1}{2}", otherClientMessage.From, otherClientMessage.Message, Environment.NewLine);
                        chatTextBox.Text += displayMessage;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (RpcException )
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `notifyObservers` method is asynchronous but has a `void` return type, which means you can't await it. You're effectively *starting* the method, and returning as soon as you hit the first `await` operator that uses an incomplete awaitable (the first `WriteAsync` call, probably).

You then return the task with a `ReservationResponse`, and the operation completes.

When that first awaitable call completes, `notifyObservers` will continue, but at that point the operation has already completed, so when you try to write to the response stream, the system will throw the error you're seeing.

I strongly suspect you should return a `Task` from `notifyObservers` and await that from your main entry method:

```
// Names changed to be conventional C#
public override async Task<ReservationResponse> SaveReservation(
    global::Res.Protocol.ReservationRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
{
    // some code for saving my reservation in repository database
    ReservationResponse response = new Res.Protocol.ReservationResponse
    {
        Type = ReservationResponse.Types.Type.Savereservation,
        Journey = GetProtoJourney(journey)
    };

    await NotifyObserversAsync(response);

    // Note: no Task.FromResult, as you're in an async method. The response
    // will already be wrapped in a task.
    return new ReservationResponse
    {
        Type = ReservationResponse.Types.Type.Savereservation
    };
}

public async Task NotifyObserversAsync(Res.Protocol.ReservationResponse response)
{
    foreach (var ob in responseStreams)
    {
        await ob.WriteAsync(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: I modified the method as you suggested. The exception is not thrown anymore, but the updated code is never reached. I made a test in login() method: I iterate through all my observers and I make an SaveReservationResponse (as in my NotifyObserversAsync method). If my IServerStreamWriter object is not the current IServerStreamWriter object from the list of method's parameters, my update method is not called for a previous  IServerStreamWriter object from the list.

Comment: @CatalinHoria: Ah - I think I see the problem. I hadn't read the question carefully enough to notice that they're streams from a different operation. If your `Login` method is adding to the list of the streams, when do you expect each `Login` method to complete? It would be helpful if you could rewrite the question with a [mcve] - we don't need to see the Java, but more complete server code would help a lot.

Comment: Every client will have the logout option (it's not implemented yet in server code) where I'll delete it from the observers list. This is the time when I expect my login() 
method for that client to complete.

Comment: @CatalinHoria: Right. You'll have a natural race condition there, unless you have some sort of locking. I'm going to delete this answer shortly, as I don't think I'd understood it properly - but if you could provide a [mcve] that would really make things easier.

Comment: I reproduced my problem from the real app via a minimal example. Login method (which is server streaming one) should send a notify response to all connected clients when a new client connects to server. But the response is never sent if the stream isn't the stream given as parameter from method. I attach C# server and  Java client implementations : [C# server](https://github.com/catahoria/gRPC-server) [Java client](https://github.com/catahoria/gRPC-client)

Comment: @CatalinHoria: Please edit this - ideally both a C# server *and* C# client, for simplicity - into the question. (Again, I'd recommend following C# naming conventions as well.)

Comment: @CatalinHoria: Right, in this case you *do* have the problem I described - you're completing a response (by getting to the end of the method) but holding onto the response stream and writing to it later on. You need to *not finish* the operation until you're really done.

Comment: Thank you. Your answers opened my eyes. But how can I prevent the response stream from completing itself?  In Java there is `onCompleted` method which completes a stream. I didn't find something similar in C#. Is there a solution to use streams from my responseStreams list in different methods (from server) at different client requests times? For instance: The server gets a request and the `Login` method is called where I add the stream in my list. Now the server gets another request, but this time `Chat` method is called and I have to send a broadcast message to all my streams from my list.

Comment: @CatalinHoria: "But how can I prevent the response stream from completing itself?" - by not returning from the async method. Basically, when the method completes, the response will complete (as I understand it; I haven't done much gRPC server side stuff).